# cuda kernel for loop too long?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda

After some long time consuming hand-tuning and half-devide naive debugging, i finally find some reason for the crash of my kernel. Is it you can't make a for loop too long in kernel?
Here is the Minimal Complete and Verifiable code: 
the error is : unspecified launch failure

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char uchar;

struct NodePointer {
    int id;
    uchar dist;
    int idintree;
    NodePointer() :id(0), dist(0), idintree(-1){}
};
struct TreeNode {
    NodePointer father;
    NodePointer children[4];
    int id;
    int childrenNum;
    int idintree;
    TreeNode() :id(0), childrenNum(0), idintree(-1){}
};

__global__ void
kernel4(int NumTN, TreeNode* tempthistree, int size)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (index < NumTN)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            TreeNode node1 = tempthistree[i];
            printf("              node %d in tree %d, its id in tree is %d, its child num is %d\n", i, index, node1.idintree, node1.childrenNum);

        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n1 = 33417;
    TreeNode * testtree;
    cudaMallocManaged(&testtree, n1*sizeof(TreeNode));
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        TreeNode c;
        c.idintree = i;
        c.id = i;
        c.father.id = i - 1;
        c.father.dist = 1;
        c.childrenNum = i % 4;
        int aaa = i % 4;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            c.children[j].dist = j;
            c.children[j].id = 1;
            c.children[j].idintree = 10;
        }
        testtree[i] = c;
    }


    kernel4 << <1, 1 >> >(4000, testtree, n1);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("Kernel3 error :%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: @talonmies      would you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Windows, you might be running into a Timeout Detection and Recovery issue, meaning your kernel execution time is too long.

See this answer:
[C++: Simple CUDA volume reconstruction code crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385087/c-simple-cuda-volume-reconstruction-code-crashing#answer-35412869)

Answer (score 0):

First, the kernel call : `kernel4 << <1, 1 >> >(4000, testtree, n1)`

You are using 1 block with only 1 thread. So your index only goes to 0 here. You are giving this thread the following task : CPU, please perform a for loop. So there is no parallelism right there.

You can use a for loop in a kernel, but I suggest in your case to put it outside. At least here's a possibility :

```
__global__ void
kernel4(int NumTN, TreeNode* tempthistree, int size) 
{
    int index = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    for (int i=0;i<NumTN;i++)
    {
        if (index < size)
        {
            TreeNode node1 = tempthistree[index];
            printf("node %d in tree %d, its id in tree is %d, its child num is %d\n", index, i, node1.idintree, node1.childrenNum);

        }
    }
}
```

Now you need more threads, n1 minimum. There's a limit of 1024 threads (nowadays) in one block, so you need more block to reach n1. For example ceil(n1/1024) blocks.

Futhermore, I'm not sure in C, but be careful when using arrays in structures. Try a short example with memory transfer to see if you get the correct answers (I had some problems with fortran).

PS : Also check youre compute capability : printf is only available on GPUs with compute capability >= 2.0.

Comment: kernel4<<<1,1>>> is only a test, the problem is Window TDR . Thanks all the way